# What is the inverse of $f(x) = x^3/6 - 36/x$?

Tags: inverse-function, cubics

The question is:

The function $f$ is defined by:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{36}{x} , x > 0$$

Show that the function $f$ has an inverse.

I tried to use an inverse function calculator online but the result is extremely complicated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are asked to prove that it has an inverse, not to find a formula for it. Do you know enough calculus to show that it is either increasing or decreasing? (When asking questions here, please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You could sketch a graph, bearing in mind the all important $x>0$, and reflect in $y=x$

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for the tips and the link.

Comment: @Bruce Oh yes, I have not thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between asking what is the inverse and asking does an inverse exists. To answer the second question, you only need to show that the derivative is positive for all $x>0$.

Comment: ... and $\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{36}{x^2} \geq 3\sqrt{2}$ by the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could plot the function $f(x) = x^3/6 - 36/x$ for $x>0$ and apply the [horizontal line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test).

[image]

If any horizontal line $y=c$ is drawn on the above graph and intersects the graph of $f(x)$ more than once. The function is not injective i.e. we have the same $y$ value for two different values of $x$  and hence $f(x)$ is not one-to-one (injective). To add more lingo - the particular function you supplied is bijective because the horizontal line will only intercept $f(x)$ exactly once. This is a necessary condition for a function to have an inverse.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{36}{x^2}>0$ for any $x>0$ so this is an increasing function .

Therefore $f(x)$ has an inverse.

Comment: Thanks for the help!